# Storybook does not load SVGs in Components of Vue project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, storybook

I have created a Vue project with `vue-cli` and installed `storybook` later via `npm install --save-dev storybook` as a dependency to show my created components.

The storybook webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['vue-svg-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            data: '@import "./src/assets/styles/main.scss";'
          }
        }
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
    }
  )

  return config
}
```

and the story `index.js` like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue';
import Alert from '../src/components/buttons/Alert.vue';

storiesOf('Components', module)
  .add('Alert', () => ({
    components: { Alert },
    template: '<Alert />'
  }))
```

for some reason when trying to load a component which consists of a SVG I'm getting:

[image]

The component itself is displayed but the part where the SVG sits no SVG is showing.

Interestingly though it works just fine when trying to display the component in the Vue's main app. The `vue.config` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "./src/assets/styles/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule("svg");

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule.use("vue-svg-loader").loader("vue-svg-loader");
  }
};
```

Why does `storybook` does not load the svgs properly while the main Vue app can?

**Edit:** I have gone ahead and simply used webpacks `file-loader` too to make sure it has nothing to do with `vue-svg-loader`:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {},
    },
  ],
},
```

but I am getting the same error.
After trying to apply the first answer to replace `push()` to rules with `unshift()` I am getting this error: `Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag`.

**Edit2**:

This is one of the SVGs I'm trying to load:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="exclamation-triangle" class="svg-inline--fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M569.517 440.013C587.975 472.007 564.806 512 527.94 512H48.054c-36.937 0-59.999-40.055-41.577-71.987L246.423 23.985c18.467-32.009 64.72-31.951 83.154 0l239.94 416.028zM288 354c-25.405 0-46 20.595-46 46s20.595 46 46 46 46-20.595 46-46-20.595-46-46-46zm-43.673-165.346l7.418 136c.347 6.364 5.609 11.346 11.982 11.346h48.546c6.373 0 11.635-4.982 11.982-11.346l7.418-136c.375-6.874-5.098-12.654-11.982-12.654h-63.383c-6.884 0-12.356 5.78-11.981 12.654z"></path></svg>
```

**Edit3**: *Alert.vue in `projectroot/src/components/banners/Alert.vue`, Webpack config of Storybook is in `projectroot/.storybook/webpack.config.js`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="show" :class="`alert_wrap ${model}`">
    <IconBase>
      <component :is="iconComponent" />
    </IconBase>
    <div class="alert_text">
      <p v-if="title">{{ title }}</p>
      <p>{{ msg }}</p>
    </div>
    <IconBase>
      <TimesIcon @click="show = !show" aria-hidden="Close" />
    </IconBase>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import IconBase from "../icons/IconBase.vue";
import CautionIcon from "../../assets/icons/exclamation-triangle-solid.svg";
import InfoIcon from "../../assets/icons/info-circle-solid.svg";
import SuccessIcon from "../../assets/icons/check-circle-solid.svg";
import TimesIcon from "../../assets/icons/times-solid.svg";

export default {
  name: "Alert",
  components: {
    CautionIcon,
    InfoIcon,
    SuccessIcon,
    TimesIcon,
    IconBase
  },
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    title: {
      type: String
    },
    model: {
      type: String,
      default: "info",
      validator(type) {
        return ["caution", "info", "success"].includes(type);
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    iconComponent() {
      return `${this.model}-icon`;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  /* some styles depending on the props passed */
</style>
```

Comment: What does Alert.vue look like?

Comment: @Neil.Work please see my edited answer.

Comment: So if you comment out the dynamic component that you are trying to render the icons with, is the hard coded TimesIcon rendering successfully?

Comment: @Neil.Work I'm not sure, but it got solved below.

Comment: Great, that’s where I was going with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@liximomo's answer is almost correct. You should remove `svg` file from `file-loader` processing rule, but the rule search condition should be slightly different:

```js
module.exports = ({ config }) => {

    let rule = config.module.rules.find(r =>
        // it can be another rule with file loader 
        // we should get only svg related
        r.test && r.test.toString().includes('svg') &&
        // file-loader might be resolved to js file path so "endsWith" is not reliable enough
        r.loader && r.loader.includes('file-loader')
    );
    rule.test = /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)(\?.*)?$/;

    config.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['vue-svg-loader']
        }
    )

    // ...

    return config;
}
```

Another way to import SVG without changing the Webpack config rules is to specify an **inline** loader, which can be useful to avoid errors when some components already use SVG in CSS or HTML as just a file path. Example:

```js
// disable all rules with !! and use just vue-svg-loader
import CautionIcon from "!!vue-svg-loader!../../assets/icons/exclamation-triangle-solid.svg";
```

Comment: dude thanks so much, it finally works. Can you elaborate a little bit more on what was the issue? Just so that I thoroughly understand.

Comment: @supersize of course, your `svg` files were processed with `file-loader` and it just creates url for that file and imports this file just as file path string(you saw this in a console error). So the `svg` part should be removed from `file-loader` rule `test` regular expression to disable processing for such files and allow us to add custom `vue-svg-loader` loader.

Comment: @supersize as for parsing SVG issue, I think `vue-svg-loader` tried to process output URL  string from `file-loader`, because a svg part won't be correctly removed from its `test` reg exp.

Comment: But why didn't it work with only `file-loader` in the first place then?

Comment: @supersize according to your code I think you are expecting to load SVG as Vue components(you are importing svg and placing them to `components` section) but `file-loader` has completely different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Because `storybook` already has a `file-loader` to emit your `svg` as an asset. We should exclude `svg` from `file-loader` first.

```js
// exclude svg from existing rule
config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
  if (rule.loader && rule.loader.endsWith('file-loader')) {
    return {
      ...rule,
      test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)(\?.*)?$/,
    };
  }

  return rule;
});

// now we can add our svg loader
config.module.rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['vue-svg-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            data: '@import "./src/assets/styles/main.scss";'
          }
        }
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Appreciate it. I have gone ahead and tried your recommended solution but I got a new error `Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag`. I have also gone ahead and changed it back to `file-loader` which gives me the exact same error as in my original post.

Comment: You should also exclude svg from file-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UTF-8 encoding?

Error you having

> Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag

use to be related with encoding using Byte-Order-Mark (BOM).

> "Zero width no-break space" unicode character which Windows systems
>   automatically prepend to utf-8 files

If you inspect the file with hex editor you can see the culprit.

You can manually change encoding to "without BOM" or perform replacement with something like replace("\ufeff", "") before you load the file.

If you used an editor maybe you have configuration for specific "with BOM" encoding. For example in notepad++
[image: N++ encoding]

Code to add jsx option

```
 loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        jsx: true,
      },
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have gone ahead and edited my OP to include the SVG. I don't see any `without BOM` in there. It is Fontawesomes SVG btw.

Comment: It is internal from file. Althought it is a SVG it has an internal encoding. Probably the tool you using or when you create the SVG has been encoded with UTF-8 with BOM then now you are trying to parse and find BOM character that cant parse then fails. UTF-8 also exist without BOM. BOM is not needed. Encoding of SVG file must be the one that your receptor can manage. Encodings are a hell. If you can change encoding try to use Base64 simple one. Are you using Notepad++?

Comment: I am not using Notepad++, I actually didn't touch the file at all. It is from Fontawesome, so I just downloaded this file: `https://fontawesome.com/icons/exclamation-triangle?style=solid` and imported it.

Comment: Are you finally using file-loader or svg-loader? Use file-loader and add the option  jsx: true. I edit post to add the code.

Comment: I have tried `vue-svg-loader` and `file-loader`, both give me the error in my OP. It doesn't really matter which one to use. Trying the JSX true now.